# how to increase the listview loading speed in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I have 2000 list items in my list view. But it takes long time to load. Since my application become very slow. If anybody faced the same issue and got solution, could you please share your idea to fix the same.

Comment: For better suggestions, you might also want to include how you are currently displaying your `ListView`, what is the source of the data for the data in question, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You should try the "Loaders API" :
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

in order to load asynchronously your list's adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Load More button at the end of screen. For this refer [Android Listview with load more button](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/). Where you find the demo for this same.